# “Everybody goes crazy”. Is the sentence correct?

Tags: grammatical-number

What kind of verb should be placed after 'Everybody' - singular or plural?

Is it necessary to place 's/es' after a verb?

For example, which of the following sentences is correct?

1. "Everybody goes crazy"
2. "Everybody go crazy"

Comment: The second would be correct only if it represents an imperative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Everybody is singular, therefore it takes singular verb forms, and "everybody goes crazy" is correct. "Everybody go crazy" would only be correct for a command, as the third-person singular imperative form of "go" is "go".

Comment: +1 for mentioning imperative.  If the sentence was an imperative wouldn't the correct punctuation  be: *Everybody, go crazy.* (with a comma, exclamation mark being optional).

Comment: well, you have many different choices of punctuation. You could put a dash ("Everybody—go crazy"), a colon ("Everybody: go crazy"), or, yes, a comma ("Everybody, go crazy"). Of course, in speech there is no punctuation, so if we're just talking about whether the sequence of words "everybody go crazy" is grammatical or not, it is.

Comment: @nohat - I'd probably punctuate it like this: _Everybody, go crazy!_

Comment: @J.R. Is saying “God protect you” instead of saying “God protects you” considered an imperative form? If so is the case would you put punctuation after “God”? To be, “God, protect you”?

Answer (score 5):

Both sentences, ''Everybody goes crazy'' and ''Everybody go crazy'' are grammatically correct.

While the former means that everybody has the tendency of getting crazy in a given situation, the latter refers to a command or statement asking everybody that they should go crazy.

Hope it makes sense?