# Why is "can they" referring to "everybody" grammatical?

Tags: pronouns, singular-vs-plural, tag-questions, singular-they

> Everybody can not be intelligent, can they?
>
> Everything is bright and beautiful, isn't it?

Why first sentence takes 'they' (plural)  But second one takes 'it' (singular)?

Comment: Note that [Everybody is **singular,** therefore it takes singular verb forms.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/16592/126) The tag question ***can they?*** in your first example is a "singular they" usage. The reason it's ***they*** in #1 and ***it*** in #2 is simply that *[every] **body*** refers to each *human being*, and we don't call a person ***it***.

Answer (score 7):

Most indefinite pronouns (everybody, everything, nothing, nobody etc.) are singular; hence subject–verb agreement requires that we use a singular verb with them, and other pronouns pertaining to them must be singular. So why "they" in

> Everybody can not be intelligent, can they?

The answer is that **this "they" isn't plural**. It's called [singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they):

> Singular they is the use in English of the pronoun they, or its inflected or derivative forms, such as them, their, or themselves, as a "pronoun that is neutral between masculine and feminine", to refer to a single person or an antecedent that is grammatically singular.

Simply put, a writer can write "I don't know them" rather than "I don't know him/her".

If you're interested and want to read more, these can make for a useful reading:

- [Is there a correct gender-neutral singular pronoun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus)
- [The hidden flaw in "singular they"—what reflexive pronoun to use?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216617/the-hidden-flaw-in-singular-they-what-to-do-about-reflexive-pronouns)

Comment: thank you so much but why the second sentence takes 'it' while everything is also a singular indefinite pronoun.

Comment: @Ravi you need to elaborate on what your question is. Isn't there an agreement between the counts of 'it' and 'everything', as you pointed out?